# Docker cannot delete device mapper

Tags: docker, cron, cpu, redhat, device-mapper

Good morning,

I have crons which launches containers to run python scripts. When these containers are launched. We have the CPU load which is skyrocketing. This means that containers cannot delete the associated device mapper. Also, the containers don't disappear after running the script because of this.

For the moment, I have just reduced the rate at which the scripts are launched by the crons. The only way I have found to resolve the problem when I lose control of the server due to the CPU is to restart the server.

Can you tell me how to resolve this problem please?

Information:
OS server --> Linux Red Hat version 7.9
Docker version --> Docker version 1.9.1, build ab77bde/1.9.1